# Xcode Unknown type name 'IplImage'?

Tags: xcode, opencv, iplimage

I have the following code:

```
IplImage *im_rgb = [self CreateIplImageFromUIImage:input_image];
IplImage *im_gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(im_rgb),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
```

I encountered this error: `Unknown type name 'IplImage'`.

I am using the project provided by this link https://github.com/agnivsen/Exemplar
But I have imported my own opencv library. I am not sure if it triggered the problem.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: You've provided too little information for people to help you properly, add more detail to you question. Guessing: Have you imported the appropriate headers of the OpenCV library into your source? If yes then what does Xcode's show definition operation give you?

Comment: please do **not** use opencv's deprecated c-api. stick with c++, cv::Mat.

Comment: How can I check if I get the correct header?